# Magento 2.3.1 - Payment methods api

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, rest-api, payment-gateway

I have a payment module for Magento 2.2 for one Croatian online payment provider, i tried it to install on Magento 2.3.1 and everything is fine but when i want to go on Checkout it says 
https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/auIzs7o1NSN0KyEoq6jHv5MJkbcnUbC7/estimate-shipping-methods  - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () and i have no shipping methods?

[image]
Any help??ž

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To enable php display errors, please go to file : `app/bootstrap.php` and uncomment the line `ini_set: ('display_errors', 1);`

Try loading the URL in the browser again.  See what you get.  That should be enough in your case.

Remember to undo your change after.

More debugging methods can be found here:

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/debug-technique-in-magento-2/

Comment: This could have been a comment as it is not a actual answer

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar If he loads the URL that is throwing 500 this is an answer.  The question was `Any help?`

Comment: Solution of error that is displayed on tha URL , would be the actual solution to answer in my opinion . Debugging is identifying the problem not a solution .

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Semantics.  Identifying a problem is working towards a solution.  And again, the question was `Any help?`.  I think that's open enough for this answer.